# BPM finder with Android

Tags: android

I've been trying to find a way to detect the BPM of any song in Android and couldn't come up with any other solution than to tap on the screen to the tempo to get the bpm.

Is there a way to use the phone mic to listen to a song and automatically get the bpm of the song?

I kinda need pointers in the right direction cause I couldn't find any way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

Check this : http://www.pogo.org.uk/~mark/bpm-tools/

source code is also available, you can build an executable or a jni libaray with the source code.